# Python error: 'int' object has no attribute 'toordinal' (Using Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 series with the same index. The index is time series in the format: YYYY-MM-DD. I am trying to plot both the series using matplotlib and this is the code:

```
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

The series look like:
x---->

```
Date
2011-01-31    3.0
2011-02-28    10.0
2011-04-30    20.0
```

y---->

```
Date 
2010-12-31    1.001111
2011-01-31    11.146155
2011-02-28    32.259745
```

The lag of 1 month doesn't seem to be the issue since combining the 2 series to a dataframe is not helping either. Does anyone know what the error means?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Your example is working fine. My pandas version is 0.22.0, and matplotlib is 2.2.2